# Why is the complement of the fat Cantor set dense?

Tags: real-analysis

Why is the complement of the [fat Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Cantor_set) dense? How can I prove it?

Comment: a lexical proof: it's the complement of a nowhere dense set :D

Comment: What Cronus means is that the Cantor set contains no intervals, so its complement meets every interval, which is what being dense means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Show that if $x$ and $y$ are distinct points of a fat Cantor set $C$, one of the removed intervals lies between $x$ and $y$. This follows from the fact that if $\ell_n$ is the maximum length of the closed intervals that remain at stage $n$ of the construction of $C$, then $\ell_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Aren't all intervals that remain at stage $n$ the same size? And the length has to tend to zero, because if it didn't, joining $2^n$ of them for $n$ large enough would give you something with measure greater than 1. But I don't know how that helps in showing that one of the removed intervals lies between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @Weltschmerz: (Apparently I didn’t see this back in 2014.) Suppose that $x,y\in C$ and $x\ne y$. Choose $n$ big enough so that $\ell_n<|x-y|$; then $x$ and $y$ cannot be in the same closed interval remaining at stage $n$, so one of the earlier stages must have removed an interval between $x$ and $y$.